# TensorFlow object detection module import issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I started to learn object detection with TensorFlow from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWFg6R5ccOc&t=3s) but have some problems with `trainer` import module.

I've downloaded Tensorflow [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) and [protoc-3.4.0-win32](https://github.com/google/protobuf) and already compiled `object_detection\protos` for Python, also prepared images with labels and set enviroment variables.

Now everything is fine but an error occurs while running `3_train.py` script from [this repo](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/TensorFlow_Tut_3_Object_Detection_Walk-through):

`File "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\TensorFlow\TensorFlow_Tut_3_Object_Detection_Walk-through-master\3_train.py", line 11, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
ImportError: cannot import name 'trainer'`

I don't know how to fix this error. I'am using Python 3.6.6 on Win7x64.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: There is a file name trainer.py just move to folder (relative) to where you are currently invoking the train.py from. I had to do this to when trying to train

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to clone the github repo for tensorflow object detection models. https://github.com/tensorflow/models. 3_train.py needs object_detection/trainer.py.

Best regards.